# magento 2 Save custom attribute customer not working

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I am using magento 2.1.4
I have created some attribute for customer
When i save, this attribute not woking
Pls help me
http://prntscr.com/esncjv

Thanks

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1393

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure attribute gets flagged "is_system" = 0 in "customer_eav_attribute" table.

To do that, just don't forget to add "system" => false as part of attribute options array (inside install or upgrade script)

You can read more about the this issue in this article: http://www.apiworks.net/2017/10/magento-2-is-not-saving-customer-attribute.html